# How to "rsync" docker image to remote host over ssh?

Tags: docker, ssh, deployment, devops, rsync

In a deployment [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) script, I have two hosts:

- `localhost`, which is a machine, that typically builds docker images.
- `$REMOTE_HOST`, which is believed to be some production web server.

And I need to transfer locally built docker image to `$REMOTE_HOST`, in most efficient way (fast, reliable, private, storage-friendly). Up to day, I have following command in my streaming script:

`docker save $IMAGE_NAME :latest | ssh -i $KEY_FILE -C $REMOTE_HOST docker load`

This has following **PROS**:

- Utilizes "compression-on-the-fly"
- Does not stores intermediate files on both source and destination
- Does direct transfer (images may be private), that also reduces upload time and stays "[green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_energy)", in another broader terms.

However, the **CONS** are also on checkerboard: When you are involved in transferring larger images, you dont know operation progress. So you have to wait **unknown**, but sensible time, that you **cant estimate**. I heard that progress can be tracked with kinda `rsync --progress` command

But rsync seems to transfer files, and is not working good with my ol'UNIX-style commands. Of couse you can `docker load` from some file, but how to avoid it?

How can I utilize piping, to preserve above advantages? (Or is there another special tool do copy build image to remote docker host, which shows progress?)

Comment: Can you set up a private Docker registry, or use a cloud-hosted registry?  That’s almost always better than `docker save`/`load`.

Comment: @DavidMaze As my friend loves to say, "almost doesn't count" :-) I need to do direct transfers, and just wanted to add a nice progress bar to existing structure. Is that possible, while leaving all other working almost "as it previously was"?

Comment: I think the `docker save` path is fully streaming, and you don’t actually know how much data there will be until you’ve sent it all.  That makes it impossible to have a progress bar without landing the file on disk somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could invoke `pv` as part of your pipeline:

```
docker save $1:latest | pv [options...] | ssh -i $3 -C $2 docker load
```

`pv` works like `cat`, in that it reads from its standard input and writes to its standard output. Except that, like the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) says,

> **pv** allows a user to see the progress of data through a pipeline, by giving information such as time elapsed, percentage completed (with progress bar), current throughput rate, total data transferred, and ETA.

`pv` has a number of options to control what kind of progress information it prints. You should read the documentation and choose the output that you want. In order to display a percentage complete or an ETA, you will probably need to supply an expected size for the data transfer using the `-s` option.

Comment: "Need to get 48,3 kB of archives..." ahaha, that's it!

Comment: Could you do a bit of more work? I know image size up to single byte, but `ssh -C` does compression, so I dont know number of bytes.. So, the-follow-up question would be: *"what to pass to `-s` from a deployment bash script?"*

Comment: As a stub, If we believe that size of stream, compressed by `-C`, would be less that actual size => our best bet could be [`stat --printf="%s" /path/to/local/docker/image`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script)